# Expression Blend Preview for .NET 4 and vs 2010 RC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

Is anyone successfully using Expression Blend Preview for .NET 4 with the RC of VS 2010/.NET 4? I installed EBP beside Expression Blend 3 on my development machine. It launches okay, but when I try to open a solution created with VS 200, it crashes.

Has anyone else run into this? Is there a fix? Thanks.

Comment: Same thing happens to me! I just downloaded it yesterday. When I try to open a solution created in Visual Studio 2010 in Blend Preview for .NET 4, Blend crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: http://connect.microsoft.com/Expression/feedback/details/534897/blend-preview-for-net-4-crashes-when-a-new-project-is-created

It says "Expression Blend Preview for .NET 4 does not yet support .NET 4 RC, only .NET 4 Beta 2.". *Sigh*

The workaround is of course to install .NET 4 Beta 2. Here is the link: [.NET 4 Beta 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ded875c8-fe5e-4cc9-b973-2171b61fe982&displaylang=en) (from the above link)